# $\tan^2(x)y''-2\tan(x)y'+(2+\tan^2(x))y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I've been trying to solve the shown above, and I've attempted to employ a series solution method. It's relatively easy to prove that 0 is a regular singular point of this equation, and working with a proposed $y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_nx^{n+k})$. After doing a fair amount of work, I showed that $k$ had to be either zero or one, and that $\tan(x)a_1k(k+1)-2a_0k = 0$. In addition, I ended up with is $0 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(((2+\tan^2(x))a_n+(-2\tan(x)(n+k+1)a_{n+1}+\tan^2(x)(n+k+2)(n+k+1)a_{n+2})x^{n+k})$.

From here, I got stuck. I have attached a picture of my work in detail down below, so that I can present some idea of my process. I'm hoping for a) a solution and b) a faster way to get it. (This took me while and I didn't even get to the end)

[image]

Comment: $sin(x)$ and $xsin(x)$ are solutions

Comment: this is second order linear differential equation, and it fllows that evry solution is of the form $c_1\sin(x)+c_2x\sin(x)$

Comment: It's very easy :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%5E2%28x%29y%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2%E2%88%922tan%28x%29y%E2%80%B2%2B%282%2Btan%5E2%28x%29%29y%3D0

Comment: you can fllow the steps of resolution of a second order differential equation

Comment: How is it linear?

Comment: First: it's linear because there is only linear combinations of $y,y',y'', y^{(3)}\cdots$, but you have to read definitions, this is very important in mathematimatics :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Second-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html , Second do you know why your question is downvoted? because first there is an image (it's always better to use latex to present your work), you have to specify your question clearly, The answer can follows easly from definitions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan^2(x)(y''+y)+\frac{2}{\cos(x)}\left(y\cos(x)-y'\sin(x)\right)=0$$
$y''+y=0$ and $y\cos(x)-y'\sin(x)$ have a common solution $y=\sin(x)$ Hense this is a solution of the ODE.

Then, let $y(x)=\sin(x)g(x)$

$y'=\cos(x)g+\sin(x)g'$

$y''=-\sin(x)g+2\cos(x)g'+\sin(x)g''$

that we bring back into the ODE :
$$\tan^2(x)\left(-\sin(x)g+2\cos(x)g'+\sin(x)g''+\sin(x)g\right)++\frac{2}{\cos(x)}\left(\sin(x)g\cos(x)-(\cos(x)g+\sin(x)g')\sin(x)\right)=0$$
after simplification the only remaining term is : $g''=0$

Integration leads to $g(x)=c_1+c_2x$
$$y(x)=g(x)\sin(x)=c_1\sin(x)+c_2x\sin(x)$$

Comment: So, basically, observe sin(x) is a solution and use reduction of order.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\tan^2(x)y''-2\tan(x)y'+(2+\tan^2(x))y=0$

$\sin^2(x)y''-2\sin(x)\cos(x)y'+(2\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))y=0$

Let $u=\sin(x)$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac{du}{dx}=\cos(x)\dfrac{dy}{du}$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\cos(x)\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)=\cos(x)\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)-\sin(x)\dfrac{dy}{du}=\cos(x)\dfrac{d}{du}\left(\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}-\sin(x)\dfrac{dy}{du}=\cos(x)\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}\cos(x)-\sin(x)\dfrac{dy}{du}=\cos^2(x)\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}-\sin(x)\dfrac{dy}{du}$

$\therefore\sin^2(x)\left(\cos^2(x)\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}-\sin(x)\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)-2\sin(x)\cos^2(x)\dfrac{dy}{du}+(2\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))y=0$

$\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}-\sin(x)(\sin^2(x)+2\cos^2(x))\dfrac{dy}{du}+(2\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))y=0$

$u^2(1-u^2)\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}-u(2-u^2)\dfrac{dy}{du}+(2-u^2)y=0$

Let $y=uv$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{du}=u\dfrac{dv}{du}+v$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}=u\dfrac{d^2v}{du^2}+\dfrac{dv}{du}+\dfrac{dv}{du}=u\dfrac{d^2v}{du^2}+2\dfrac{dv}{du}$

$\therefore u^2(1-u^2)\left(u\dfrac{d^2v}{du^2}+2\dfrac{dv}{du}\right)-u(2-u^2)\left(u\dfrac{dv}{du}+v\right)+(2-u^2)uv=0$

$u^3(1-u^2)\dfrac{d^2v}{du^2}+2u^2(1-u^2)\dfrac{dv}{du}-u^2(2-u^2)\dfrac{dv}{du}-u(2-u^2)v+u(2-u^2)v=0$

$u^3(1-u^2)\dfrac{d^2v}{du^2}+u^2(2-u^2)\dfrac{dv}{du}=0$

$u(1-u^2)\dfrac{d^2v}{du^2}=(u^2-2)\dfrac{dv}{du}$